# AngularJS way of [PrototypeJS] Event.observe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototypejs

Thanks for viewing this thread. I have this scenario in which I am having a problem implementing this **PrototypeJS [Event.observe]** method within **AngularJS**.

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    Event.observe(window, "load", function() {
        console.log("event triggered!");
        // others statements here...
    });
});
```

I've tried placing the `Event.observe()` outside the controller area, it worked but the behaviour is that the `Event.observe()` got triggered first before `MyCtrl` in which should be the other way around.

I was planning to implement some sort of directive for `Event.observe()` yet I'm not sure if that's the right solution for this.

If you have greater suggestion or clarification, I am open for it.

Comment: Have you tried using an artificial event, fired from within your Angular code, and observed from outside it? I suspect that the $scope is your issue here, I don't know very much about Angular, but I believe that it defines its own space where events happen, and that may be limiting what you can observe from within it. (inside) someElement.fire('my:event'); (outside) Event.observe('my:event', function(evt, memo){ /* do something */ });

Comment: So basically instead of using `Event.observe` of PrototypeJS, I should use `$scope.$watch` of AngularJS?

Comment: No, just have your angular element fire an event, and watch that from outside of the container. $('whatever').fire('my:event'); and then document.observe('my:event', function(evt){ /* do your worst here */ });